# Read a large SQL script file in c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am trying to read a large script, thus far I have tried two options:

**Option 1:**

We can't open large script files in SQL management studio because of the issue of out of memory space, so Initially I used `sqlcmd` to execute 160 mb SQL script file on remote host, after 55 minutes some rows were effected with this error, `TCP Provider: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. , communication link failure.`

**Option 2:**

Now I am trying using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40830/2218697) example, the file size is 160 MB with lot of insert statements, but Visual Studio crashes

**Code:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   string scriptDirectory = "e:\\";
   string sqlConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
   "Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS";
   DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(scriptDirectory);
   FileInfo[] rgFiles = di.GetFiles("*.sql");
   foreach (FileInfo fi in rgFiles)
   {
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(fi.FullName);
        string script = fileInfo.OpenText().ReadToEnd(); // here visual studio crashes
        SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString);
        Server server = new Server(new ServerConnection(connection));
        server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery(script);
   }

       return View();
}
```

**Screen Shot:**

[image]

Comment: Does your script contains `GO` separators? Or there are just `INSERT...` lines?

Comment: Why is *Visual Studio* reading the file at all? It's not clear why you're executing your code within the Visual Studio executable. (Additionally, please format your code to make it more readable.)

Comment: @Dennis, yes it contains `GO` separators because the script file was generated with Generate script wizard in Sql management studio.

Comment: If there are only `INSERT`s and `GO`s, then it's rather easy to parse this file manually. Just read file line-by-line, skip `GO` statements, and execute one `INSERT` statement per `SqlCommand`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, I have made the changes , thanks.

Comment: @Dennis, i am migrating to new database with  `schema and data` , so it contains all , create, insert, alter, hope you understand.

Comment: Have you explored other options, like with the Import and Export wizard? If you still have access to the legacy database, that could be a viable alternative.

Comment: @Matthew Haugen i have tried `import export wizard` in sql, here are the [issues](http://www.sqlmatters.com/Articles/Common%20Issues%20with%20the%20SQL%20Server%20Import%20and%20Export%20Wizard.aspx) with it, and i can break script into smaller parts but again its time consuming, i can run script file which is 20 mb in sql management studio, i just posted this question to know weather we can read large file in c#.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest executing the insert statements line by line optionally wrapped in a transaction:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    string scriptDirectory = "e:\\";
    string sqlConnectionString = "Integrated Security=SSPI;" +
        "Persist Security Info=True;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS";

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(sqlConnectionString))
    {
        var transaction = connection.BeginTransaction();
        using(var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            ProcessFiles(command, scriptDirectory);
        }
        transaction.Commit();
    }
    return View();
}

private void ProcessFiles(SqlCommand command, string scriptDirectory)
{
    foreach(var file in Directory.GetFiles(scriptDirectory,"*.sql"))
    {
        using(var reader = new StreamReader(file))
        {
            while(!reader.EndOfStream)
            {
                var line = reader.ReadLine();
                if(!line.StartsWith("GO"))
                {
                    command.CommandText = line;
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
        }
    }        
}
```

Keep in mind that this will put some pressure on the log file of the database.