# EF add-migration throwing System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, entity-framework, out-of-memory

When I try to add a migration file through PM I get an out of memory exception. Anyone else had this problem before and happen to know how to fix it? So far I have tried re installing VS 2013 to no avail

Monitoring my memory usage I have 12GB available, and it is using less than 8 while the add migration is running, so should be plenty available. Below is the output

```
PM> add-migration test
```

> System.OutOfMemoryException: Exception of type
>   'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.    at
>   System.AppDomain.DoCallBack(CrossAppDomainDelegate callBackDelegate)
>   at System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Run(BaseRunner
>   runner)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Design.ToolingFacade.Scaffold(String
>   migrationName, String language, String rootNamespace, Boolean
>   ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.Execute(String name,
>   Boolean force, Boolean ignoreChanges)    at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.AddMigrationCommand.<>c__DisplayClass2.<.ctor>b__0()
>   at
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.MigrationsDomainCommand.Execute(Action
>   command) Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.

Comment: Maybe give this a look. I have experienced this issue before, but never from executing a command in the Nuget console. Hopefully it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186256/net-out-of-memory-exception-used-1-3gb-but-have-16gb-installed

Comment: this means the Virtual Memory of devenv.exe is full. use less VS extensions

Comment: @magicandre1981 Thanks for the suggestion, but I only have 12 extensions installed, that includes the ones I cant remove such as microsoft advertising SDKs, and other ones. I have only installed a few myself, not sure I can really use any less

Comment: @DrewKennedy thanks for the link there. Can confirm that I am targeting Any CPU, and haven't really changed anything there recently. I can confirm that this used to work until a few days ago

Comment: run vmmap.exe and select the devenv.exe and look how much free virtual memory do you still have: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/dd535533.aspx

Comment: @magicandre1981 VMMap shows as the task is running the free memory is reducing, at the point the exception is thrown, there is about 400MB free memory available

Comment: I also tried running VS in safe mode, so add in should not be enabled, and it still has the same results, free memory is about 600MB at time the exception is thrown, manual refresh, so may be a little out

Answer (score 25):

Simply restarting Visual Studio worked for me in this case.

Comment: Yes it worked for me after restarting. That's why we consider "restart" such a magical solution!!!

Comment: Yes, that works also for me but I prefer to have a solution without having to restart VS.

Answer (score 4):

Just leaving a note here in case anyone has the same error. I have fixed the issue now. I disabled ReSharper, and it started working. I then re-enabled re sharper and cleared its cache, and it continues to work now with re sharper enabled. Credit to magicandre1981 for pointing me towards the add-ins.

**EDIT:** The ReSharper version I'm using is 8.2 c# edition, build 8.2.0.2160

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I also use ReSharper (2017.2) but do not want to disable it. Instead I disabled all other extensions that I do not use regularly. I also uninstalled all unneeded workloads. This not only solved the OutOfMemoryException but also decreased the project load time tremendously.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this happen to me.  I slowly retraced my steps, and removed DbSets in the dbContext one-by-one until it worked again.

Answer (score 0):

Its solved in Visual Studio 2015 with [Automatic feature suspension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750639.aspx). You will get a popup like below.

[image]

Just click on **Re-enable**.