# System.OutOfMemoryException occurred in System.Drawing.dll with big quantity of picture

Tags: c#, .net

I have a folder with height quantity of geolocated file, I want to make a KML with the placemark.
No problem for the XML(KML) document, but the image are big and i want create a thumb(1/10) and small image (1/4) in separated folder.
The image are 4000x3000 allround 5mb, for little quantity not have problem but when the folder containg more of 35 image (in debug) i have the problem.
I have try with disposable object used with Using, `GC.collect` to only image elaboration, but nothing.

I have folder to elaborate with 1400 image or more...is possible make to work this application with it?

```
public static class MyClass_img
{
    public static void ResizeImage(Image image, int width, int height, string pathImage)
    {
        using (var destImage = new Bitmap(width, height))
        {
            destImage.SetResolution(image.HorizontalResolution, image.VerticalResolution);

            using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(destImage))
            {
                graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
                graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                using (var wrapMode = new ImageAttributes())
                {
                    wrapMode.SetWrapMode(WrapMode.TileFlipXY);

                    var destRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height);
                    graphics.DrawImage(image, destRect, 0, 0, image.Width, image.Height, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, wrapMode);
                }
            }

            destImage.Save(pathImage);
        }
        GC.Collect();
    }

    public static string imageReduce(Image img, string path, int percentValue, string extension, string folder)
    {
        var dirName = new DirectoryInfo(path).Parent.Name;
        string pathImg = folder + dirName + "_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(path) + extension;
        AprItalia_img.ResizeImage(img, img.Width / percentValue, img.Height / percentValue, pathImg);
        return pathImg;
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: You're probably not disposing the image you pass into `imageReduce(Image img, ...)`.

Comment: Don't do `GC.Collect()` unless really required since frequent cleanup increases processing pressure.

Comment: Also what is the RAM your system has?

Comment: i have 16gb, but i hav read this ... is possible have excepption beacose use all of 1.2gb, ok is possible update to 4gb, but why it have all in memory? i think is necessary only the XML file, the image are saved in the folder and the object are dispose
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186256/net-out-of-memory-exception-used-1-3gb-but-have-16gb-installed

Comment: I have set build to 64bit ...use all memory, for the moment have elaborate allround 500 file ...use all the ram of the system, but i not undestand why use all the ram...i dispose the image object and the other is only xml file

Answer (score 0):

> You do not have to call GC.Collect().

As per [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.dispose(v=vs.110).aspx),

> Always call Dispose before you release your last reference >to the Image. Otherwise, the resources it is using will not >be freed until the garbage collector calls the Image >object's Finalize method

So in your case,it seems to be going for finalize.Also are you also releasing the Image object by calling it's dispose?