# Webjob getting 'System.OutOfMemoryException'

Tags: c#, azure, memory, webjob

I have a webjob running on Azure on their S3 standard platform meaning it has 7 gb of ram available to run my app.

On the machine 3 jobs are running of which one is the one doing all the processing and the other two handles small tasks. My problem lies in the fact that I on certain memoryintensive large tasks gets a memory exception meaning that results in the given job crashing.

The job I try to run is a very memory intensive job, and requires around 1,5 gb of ram, but based on the graph below I do not understand how this should be a problem since I never am above 2.2gb of used ram for the app service. I do have to add, that I run 3 instances, so it might be that one instance is using way more memory, but I can not find anywhere to view that information.

[Memory consumption on server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdqPl.png)

When I look in the process explorer in the Kudo I see I use around 1.3gb of ram currently, which is still way below the needed memory for the job.

[Kudo screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4LNF.jpg)

The job has run without any problems no more than 2 days ago on the same server setup, so I am completely lost as to where to look.

Update: Code works fine in visual studio with same data running the same exact task.

Do anyone have ideas as to how to approach this problem

Comment: Have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186256/net-out-of-memory-exception-used-1-3gb-but-have-16gb-installed

Comment: Very relevant, and I am aware of the max 2gb limitation in most datatypes. I work with files in the size of 500-700 mb in xml and csv files. The program have been running for months without any problem, until 2 days ago and now it no longer runs with certain sizes giving me the memory exception. I tested the code in visual studio on the same data, and it works as it should

Answer (score 0):

Per my understanding, you could capture the memory dump in your azure app service and analyze the dump to narrow this issue. You could refer to this [tutorial](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2017/02/02/how-to-get-a-full-memory-dump-in-azure-app-services/) about how to get a full memory dump in Azure App Services. Also, you could leverage the **Crash Diagnoser** extension to monitor the CPU and Memory, for more details you could refer to this [blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2016/01/20/how-to-capture-dump-when-intermittent-high-cpu-happens-on-azure-web-app/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. Problem with memory dump is, that I don't know when the crash will happen, and the memory dump as far as I understand is only a snapshot. The crash diagnoser I definitely will read up, that name sounds promising :)

Answer (score -1):

Well well well  first  of all how do you  deal with Garbage  collector ?! i mean do you  dispose  disposable objects  after  they  will  do their tasks.   You said  app is being  run  for 2 days  ,  seems app has  clashed with  more  intensive  memory  loading  stuff.  As  you  said  your  app  is "very memory intensive" , i guess  you should fetch it out  (source code)  and  make sure you are managing  objects correctly,  because  garbage collector  couldn't  care all of your  "source code mess".  Good  luck.

Comment: I said the job ran without any problems just two days ago. I also ran the same job an hour ago locally in visual studio with the same data without any problems.
I keep the scopes as limited as possible, and make sure to optimize usage. Just hard when you get 500-700mb xml files to keep the overhead below twice the size of the data