# Why does my physical memory not reach 100% capacity when I attempt to flood-fill an array?

Tags: arrays, memory, memory-management, capacity

As an experiment I created a program in Delphi which simply instantiates an array and continually increases its size (populating it simultaneously) until an EOutOfMemory expection is raised. When monitoring my PC's physical memory, the capacity only reaches about 80%. Why does it not reach 100 %?

[image: Physical Memory monitored with Windows Task Manager]
[image: Physical Memory monitored with Windows Task Manager II]

Comment: That is [1.3GB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14186256/11683), isn't it?

Comment: The index refers to the number of items which the array could store before the error was raised.

Comment: And the items in question happen to be bytes?

Comment: Yes, of the Byte type in Delphi/Pascal.

Comment: So this number of Bytes is in fact [1.3GB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14186256/11683)?

Comment: Yes, I suppose it would be if converted.