# ImageResizer OutofMemory Exception

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-8, imageresizer

I have a ecommerce project and i developed ASP.NET MVC. There was no problem until a few days ago. But i've turned on output cache and i starting having problems with Image Resizer version 4.2.5. When i call some pictures http://www.blabla.com/test.jpg??format=jpeg&width=1024 my production site throw **"Out Of Memory"** exception. But my test domain not throw exception. The test domain runs very well. I've checked images resizer version and all of the web.config setting is same.

What's your suggestion? How can i up memory limit for my production domain? Or another solution?

My server is Windows Server 2012 R2 and IIS 8

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: When you compare/test between different environments are you using the same image with the same size (of image itself)?

Comment: Yes, same image and all of settings is same too. And my test domain runs on the same server.

Comment: Do you have enough memoy on the server, in the moment you get that exception  ?

Comment: Task manager show me that the server uses %37 of RAM.

Comment: `OutOfMemory` can be caused also by single collection, that exceeds 2GB memory limit - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14186256/net-out-of-memory-exception-used-1-3gb-but-have-16gb-installed/

Comment: I think it's same problem. I will try this solution. Thank you @Tigran

Comment: Does your test environment have Output Caching turned on, as well?

Comment: Yes, the output cache turned on on the test environment but there is just one different that my prod is under load but the test is not.

Comment: Please provide the diagnostics page /resizer.debug

Comment: Check that your app pool is 64 bit.