# An exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in Newtonsoft.Json.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, json

I'm getting an OutOfMemoryException when deserializing a response about 27mb in size from the API. 
It is correctly deserializing DTOs that are smaller in size. Any ideas?

```
var resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
```

Comment: It would appear you are out of memory.

Comment: Anyway to fix it? I'm able to send something that's 27mb to the API just fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : Out of Memory exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563933/c-sharp-out-of-memory-exception)

Comment: See http://www.drdobbs.com/windows/parsing-big-records-with-jsonnet/240165316