# Azure Blob Storage Out of Memory exception

Tags: exception, azure, out-of-memory, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I am using Azure Blob storage. Everything work fine, but sometime i get following error intermittently:

```
"$type": "System.Web.Http.HttpError, System.Web.Http",
"Message": "An error has occurred.",
"ExceptionMessage": "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.",
"ExceptionType": "System.OutOfMemoryException",
"StackTrace": "   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.Tasks.Task`1.ExecuteAndWait()
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.TaskImplHelper.ExecuteImplWithRetry(Func`1 impl, RetryPolicy policy)
   at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.StorageClient.CloudBlobContainer.SetPermissions(BlobContainerPermissions permissions, BlobRequestOptions options)
```

It's really hard to recreate the issue on my local. Any solutions ?

Comment: yep. Scale the Azure Web Apps tier. I assume you use Free or Shared, which both have memory limits - 1024 MB per hour. Which is calculated as Peak memory use. If your app reaches 1024MB memory usage, your site will be suspended and you will also get an Out-of-memory exception.

Comment: I am using Standard app tier with 7 GB memory.

Comment: Is it I am getting exception when I am setting permission for blob container ?

Comment: Have you looked at how much data is stored in your storage account? Overall the storage account can hold 500TB of data, however, there are other [quotas](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/azure-subscription-service-limits/#storage-limits) and [performance targets](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-scalability-targets) to be aware of

Comment: Can you provide the code that you are using to call SetPermissions?

Answer (score 1):

The following Stack Overflow thread might help [C# : Out of Memory exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563933/c-sharp-out-of-memory-exception). To summarize, if you haven't already, try changing your platform target to x64 and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

There was memory leak in the application with Windsor IOC not releasing object for  GC. That was the root problem for this error.

Comment: With respect, Windsor will release everything you tell it to. Failing to follow very simple guidance for the use of Castle Windsor ("Release everything you Resolve") is a common cause of memory leaks.