# How to withdraw ListFollower in listbox?

Tags: c#, tweetsharp

Using TweetSharp I am counting the list of followers. How can I withdraw it to the `ListBox`?

Here is the code:

```
var options = new ListFollowerIdsOfOptions() { ScreenName = "PutinRF" };
do
{
    if (cursor != null)
      options.Cursor = cursor;

    var followersList = ts.ListFollowerIdsOf(options);

    //listBox1.Items.AddRange(followersList.ToArray());

    cursor = followersList.NextCursor;

} while (cursor != 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [DataSource property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource.aspx):

```
listBox1.DataSource = followersList;
```

or look at following implementation:

```
var allIds = new List<long>();
var options = new ListFollowerIdsOfOptions() { ScreenName = "PutinRF" };
var followersIds = ts.ListFollowerIdsOf(options);
while (followersIds.NextCursor != 0)
{
   options.Cursor = followersIds.NextCursor;
   allIds.AddRange(followersIds);
}
listBox1.DataSource = allIds;
```

Comment: error: System.OutOfMemoryException. line: allIds.AddRange(followersIds);

Comment: @ArtemOlegovich please see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563933/c-sharp-out-of-memory-exception). Did you try to debug it? How many items are in the list?

Comment: for example: { ScreenName = "PutinRF", Count = 20 }. the same error =/

Comment: new exception: http://cs627224.vk.me/v627224952/8185d/ZECHSRGyKCo.jpg :) how correct it? displayed 10-15 оf people , but then appears exception...

Answer (score 0):

My decision:

```
            var options = new ListFollowerIdsOfOptions { ScreenName = "PutinRF" };
            List<long> All_ods = new List<long>();
            TwitterCursorList<long> followerIDS = ts.ListFollowerIdsOf(options);
            while(followerIDS.NextCursor!=null)
            {
                options.Cursor = followerIDS.NextCursor;

                All_ods.AddRange(followerIDS.ToArray());
                //listBox1.Items.Add(All_ods.ToArray());
                listBox1.DataSource = All_ods;
                label1.Text = "Получено: " + listBox1.Items.Count.ToString();
                break;  
            }
```

Comment: This solution is like in the answer above. I think it is not correct to set DataSource in while