# Get File.Stream using path

Tags: c#, .net, umbraco, filestream, umbraco7

I would like to get the File and pass it as stream but I'm not sure how to do this. I do have a path where the file is located. So basically using this path I'm going to retrieve this file and save it as stream. But correct me if I'm wrong, but is it correct to assume that "Reading as Stream" is something like it's actually opening the file and reading it?

Are there anyway to just retrieve or Copy the file into a FileStream or MemoryStream? Right now I have this but not sure if this is correct

```
 foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
 {
      string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
      //Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.Image
      string mediaType = Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File;
      string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
      IMedia media = Services.MediaService.CreateMedia(filename, Constants.System.Root, mediaType);
      MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
      using (Stream stream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath))
      {
           ms.WriteTo(stream);
      }
      media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, ms);
      // Save the media
      Services.MediaService.Save(media);
      media = null;
      System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
 }
```

I'm not so sure if this is the best approach. But the main goal is to retrieve that file from the path and save it in `media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, ms);` as it's requiring a `Stream` as input. How do I do this in a most efficient way? I'm always getting outofmemoryexception due to large file. So I'm guessing because it's reading it as Stream that it's throwing an error on large file. So maybe we can just copy it to save. I'm not so sure really needs help here

Update:
Here is the config to make sure I don't run out of memory

```
<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" enableVersionHeader="false" maxRequestLength="2097151" executionTimeout="50000000" targetFramework="4.5" fcnMode="Single" />

<location path="umbraco">
  <system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="204800" executionTimeout="99999"/>
  </system.web>
</location>

<security>
  <requestFiltering>
    <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="2294967295" />
  </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

And this is the build of my project

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you compiling your app for 64 bits? That will increase a lot the quantity of memory you can use.

Comment: Yeah already did

Comment: Beware that .net has a very stupid option "prefer 32 bits" in the compilation properties, if it's enabled even if you compile it for x64 it will run the program in 32 bits mode. Also, if this is running under IIS check it's executing in 64 bit mode.

Comment: @Gusman can you check if my settings are correct? I basically changed it to x64 but I'm still getting an OutOfMemoryException error when processing 1.6GB of file

Comment: Yes, it seems you have everything configured ok...

Comment: I can't even upload files that are 1.4GB in size.. I thought I can upload it since the limit should be 2gb

Comment: Check this, it may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8563933/c-sharp-out-of-memory-exception/20912869#20912869

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the code below and save yourself the trouble of opening it and then converting to a memory stream by using `FileStream`.

```
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    string filename = Path.GetFileName(filePath);
    string mediaType = Constants.Conventions.MediaTypes.File;
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(filename);
    IMedia media = Services.MediaService.CreateMedia(filename, Constants.System.Root, mediaType);
    using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open))
    {
        media.SetValue("umbracoFile", filename, fs);
        Services.MediaService.Save(media);
    }

    media = null;
    System.IO.File.Delete(filePath);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply copy `FileStream` to `MemoryStream` in .Net Framework 4+

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
using (FileStream file = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
    file.CopyTo(ms);
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question but what are the benefit of Copyig the Filestream into MemoryStream? Will this somehow solve any out of memory exception issue?

Comment: @MadzQuestioning try it once, is it solving your issue?

Comment: When debugging it's actually a more process when viewing in debugging and a split seconds delay compared to @Shoejep suggestion and it didn't solve my problem I'm still getting a OutOfMemoryException