# Running into OutOfMemoryException when serializing List of Objects which needs to be ported as JSON to a DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, datatable

I have a very large List of Objects (Totaling 186799) which I am attempting to port to a DataTable in JSON format. The total length of the Serialized list of objects is 62553299. How can I port this data from a webservice in JSON format to a DataTable in a aspx file.

```
public void GetData()
{
    DataTable dt;
    string connectionString = "----";
    string selectCommand = "SELECT -----";
    using (AdomdConnection conn = new AdomdConnection(connectionString))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (AdomdDataAdapter adapter = new AdomdDataAdapter (selectCommand, conn))
        {
            dt = new DataTable();
            adapter.Fill(dt);
            List<ResourceData> ResourceInfo = new List<ResourceData>();
            ResourceData ResourceInfoRow = null;
            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                ResourceInfoRow = new ResourceData();
                ResourceInfoRow.SourceProject = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
                ResourceInfoRow.SourceFile= dr.ItemArray[1].ToString();
                ResourceInfoRow.Project = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString();
                ResourceInfoRow.File = dr.ItemArray[3].ToString();
                ResourceInfoRow.Parent = dr.ItemArray[4].ToString();
                ResourceInfoRow.Id = dr.ItemArray[5].ToString();
                ResourceInfo.Add(ResourceInfoRow);
            }
            JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            js.MaxJsonLength = 2147483647;
            Context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(ResourceInfo)); //This is where I hit the OutOfMemoryException
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```

I have to port the data back in json format since I am using a DataTable plugin.

Thank you for your responses.

Comment: Suppose, you have a *StartOffset* and *Length* parameters and you return only limited set of result to the user, like many public APIs do(facebook, instagram, twitter etc.) Wouldn't it be better?

Comment: Obvious thing to try would be to stream to `Context.Response.OutputStream`, but [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) apparently has no methods to write to a stream so that's out.  You might consider switching to [tag:json.net] and streaming directly along the lines of [JSON.net serialize directly from oledbconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835729/json-net-serialize-directly-from-oledbconnection).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is very likely your string is to big for your memory or the string it self it to big (2gb). You try to serialize a lot of objects. So probably the best way is to split the objects into multiple chucks for serialization. Or you can try another converter like: [Newtonsoft](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializingJSON.htm). The Newtonsoft serializer is a fast and probably the most used serializer out there. The Newtonsoft serializer is also able to convert to json using a stream: [Serialize to stream](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializeWithJsonSerializerToFile.htm). Which can be directly written to the Response object.

Comment: Thanks Peter. Just realized that the point of failure occurs when attempting to write the serialized data.

Comment: As you suggested Peter, I split the data. In my aspx page, I used $.when(x,y).done(function(a,b){} to get the two json data sets and then used $.merge to combine the data.

Answer (score 0):

You apparently are running out of memory trying to serialize to a very large string, then write that string to a `Context.Response` stream.  One solution would be to use [json.net](/questions/tagged/json.net) and do something along the lines of [JSON.net serialize directly from oledbconnection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33835729/json-net-serialize-directly-from-oledbconnection), which streams directly from an [`IDataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) without ever loading the entire contents of the query into memory.  This might work with an [`AdomdDataReader`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms123475%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), though I've not tried it.

You, however, are using [`JavaScriptSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx), which has no methods to serialize directly to a stream.  Still, since what you are serializing is an `IEnumerable<T>`, it should be possible to serialize each item individually, then write each individually, manually enclosing the whole in brackets as required for a [JSON array](http://www.json.org/):

```
public static class JavaScriptSerializerExtensions
{
    public static void SerializeToStream<T>(this JavaScriptSerializer serializer, IEnumerable<T> collection, Stream stream)
    {
        if (serializer == null || collection == null || stream == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, new UTF8Encoding(false));  // DO NOT DISPOSE!
        writer.Write("[");
        long count = 0;
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        var buffer = new char[4000];
        foreach (var item in collection)
        {
            if (count > 0)
                writer.Write(",");
            sb.Length = 0;
            serializer.Serialize(item, sb);
            writer.Write(sb, buffer);
            count++;
        }
        writer.Write("]");
        writer.Flush();
    }
}

public static class TextWriterExtensions
{
    public static void Write(this TextWriter writer, StringBuilder sb, char[] buffer = null)
    {
        if (sb == null || writer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (buffer != null && buffer.Length <= 0)
            throw new ArgumentException("buffer != null && buffer.Length <= 0");
        var length = sb.Length;
        if (length <= 0)
            return;
        buffer = buffer ?? new char[Math.Min(4000, length)];
        for (int index = 0; index < length; index += buffer.Length)
        {
            var count = Math.Min(length - index, buffer.Length);
            sb.CopyTo(index, buffer, 0, count);
            writer.Write(buffer, 0, count);
        }
    }
}
```

And then do:

```
        var stream = Context.Response.OutputStream;

        var query = from dr in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
                    select new
                    {
                        SourceProject = dr.ItemArray[0].ToString(),
                        SourceFile = dr.ItemArray[1].ToString(),
                        Project = dr.ItemArray[2].ToString(),
                        File = dr.ItemArray[3].ToString(),
                        Parent = dr.ItemArray[4].ToString(),
                        Id = dr.ItemArray[5].ToString(),
                    };

        var js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        js.MaxJsonLength = 2147483647;

        js.SerializeToStream(query, stream);
```

Answer (score 0):

In short JavascriptSerializer has several overloads. If you use the one that returns a string you will be limited to StringBuilder max .ToString() capacity of just over 100.000.000 chars (string length limit thing in .net).

```
    //.Net source
    internal string Serialize(object obj, SerializationFormat serializationFormat)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        Serialize(obj, sb, serializationFormat);
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```

So instead, use the overload where you supply the StringBuilder. Then after serialization  fetch chunks of strings at a time with .ToString(index, length) not exceeding that max size of 100.000.000 or so chars.

```
    public void Serialize(object obj, StringBuilder output)
    {
        Serialize(obj, output, SerializationFormat.JSON);
    }

    //usage afterwards
    sb.ToString(0, 100000);
```

See [StringBuilder.ToString() throws OutOfMemoryException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25010604/stringbuilder-tostring-throws-outofmemoryexception)